# How to fill empty column from another table in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to fill an empty field from another table which they both have same names.
there is only 3 tables.
I don't want to do anything to `helper_id` I just need to fill the column `emp_id` when the `name` in table `person` and table `emdadgar` are equal to fill `emp_id` in table `helper` for that `name`.
here are the creation statements:

```
CREATE TABLE  "HELPER" 
   (    "HELPER_ID" NUMBER, 
    "PERSON_ID" NUMBER, 
    "EMP_ID" NUMBER, 
     CONSTRAINT "PK_HELPER" PRIMARY KEY ("HELPER_ID")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE
   )  DEFAULT COLLATION "USING_NLS_COMP"
```

```
CREATE TABLE  "EMDADGAR" 
   (    "EMP_ID" NUMBER, 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(20) COLLATE "USING_NLS_COMP", 
     CONSTRAINT "PK_EMDADGAR" PRIMARY KEY ("EMP_ID")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE
   )  DEFAULT COLLATION "USING_NLS_COMP"
```

```
CREATE TABLE  "PERSON" 
   (    "PERSON_ID" NUMBER, 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(20) COLLATE "USING_NLS_COMP", 
     CONSTRAINT "PK_PERSON" PRIMARY KEY ("PERSON_ID")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE
   )  DEFAULT COLLATION "USING_NLS_COMP"
```

```
INSERT INTO helper(emp_id)
SELECT emdadgar.emp_id FROM emdadgar
    INNER JOIN person ON person.name=emdadgar.name
    LEFT JOIN helper ON person.person_id=helper.person_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT emdadgar.emp_id FROM emdadger WHERE emdadger.emp_id=helper.emp_id);
```

this is the error:

```
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into
 ("SQL_VCLPLQLNJJURNCRCUBTRGPDCG"."HELPER"."HELPER_ID") ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721
```

this is the picture to better show the problem:
[image: related rows]

Comment: When you want to change a column value of an existing row of a table  use the `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: helper.helper_id is the primary key, so it can't be null when you insert something in that table. You could autofill it with a sequence though.

Comment: You need to update table helper, and the joins in the select statement should both be inner

Comment: I have tested the `UPDATE` statement but the error is something like this `table or view does not exist`

Comment: so I found what the problem was. firstly as @Serg said I should use UPDATE  statement and the other problem was this EMDADGAR table. it was in another schema so I should have declared it but the problem is now all of the rows have the same emp_id.

Comment: Well there was another problem, the data in `emdadgar` wasn't complete so I must've filled another field `EMDADGARID` in `emdadgar` table then merge my data from `emdadgar` to helper as `EMDADGARID` was corresponding to `emp_id` in helper table.

Answer (score 0):

We should declare the schema and use `MEREGE` statement.

```
MERGE INTO OPR.TBL_HELPER t1
USING (SELECT EMD.ID as large_id, TP.ID as person_id, EMD.PERSONELID as personel,
           EMD.EMDADGARID, TP.NAME, HL.ID as helper_id FROM SA.EMDADGAR EMD
           INNER JOIN OPR.TBL_PERSONS TP on EMD.NAME = TP.NAME
           INNER JOIN OPR.TBL_HELPER HL ON TP.ID = HL.PERSON_ID
       WHERE EMD.NAME LIKE TP.NAME AND HL.LARGE_ID is null) t2
ON (t1.PERSON_ID = t2.PERSON_ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET t1.LARGE_ID = t2.large_id;
```